# Major slowdown seen in Pixi.js with Chrome VS Firefox?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I've been using the Phaser.io 2 game engine which runs on Pixi.js as it's primary renderer. However, I've seen some stuttering in the rendering methods directly that I can't seem to pin down. On Chrome, I've managed to smooth things out but not precisely, while on Firefox things run very smoothly, and apparently in other browser and mini-browsers as well.

Today, I recorded a gif of the effect with the main Pixi.js site open in both:

https://i.gyazo.com/23ede3852844317c3abda424a06b9adc.mp4

I have asked others to look at the rendering on Chrome and they have also seen this stuttering, however in the gif, with Chrome on the left and Firefox on the right, it's very obvious something is not correct.

Is there any possible cause that should be looked at, or known issues?

Comment: When I view the main pixi.js in chrome it renders smoothly, as in the gif on the right. It's likely this issue is a local configuration, could it be that hardware acceleration in your chrome is disabled - `settings -> type 'hardware acceleration'` ?

Comment: Doh! I never even considered that, thank you. That seems to have been the case. I disabled that because in certain sites, I get diagonal lines that seem to have been caused by hardware acceleration - such as CodePen and a few others.

Comment: Several things with Javascript-heavy editors, basically.

Comment: That was also during a strange case when my CPU was stuck at 800mhz too.

Comment: That's good, I'll add it as an answer in case others have the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enabling hardware acceleration in Chrome `settings->search 'hardware acceleration'`